# Как напечатать элементы массива, индексы которых являются полными квадратами?

Tags: java, массивы, циклы

Есть задача на Java:
Напечатать те элементы массива, индексы которых являются  полными квадратами (1, 4, 9, 16, …).

Не могу понять задачу. Объясните какой нужен цикл и условие?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 int f[] =new int [10];
for (int i=0; i<f.length; i++) { 
f[i]= (int) (Math.random()*(10-0)+1)+0);
    }
    for (int i=0; i<f.length;i++) {
    System.out.print(f[i]+"");

}
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы не можете понять формулировку, или как код писать - определитесь...

Comment: Если корень из числа дает целое число, а не что-то с остатком - то оно и нужно

Comment: Как писать код программы.
Прошу прощения за неточности и безграмотность.

Answer (score 5):

Ряд полных квадратов `1, 4, 9, 16, ...` - прекрасен тем, что разности соседних чисел в нём - это последовательность нечётных чисел `3, 5, 7, ...`. На этом можно построить решение без использования умножения, используя только операции сложения:

```
int i = 1, d = 3;
while (i < array.length) {
    System.out.println(array[i]);
    i += d;
    d += 2;
}
```

Если нужно начать с нуля, то строка инициализации переменных поменяется на следующую:

```
int i = 0, d = 1;
```

PS: С использованием цикла `for` можно написать примерно тот же самый код следующим образом (начиная с нуля):

```
for (int i = 0, d = -1; i < array.length; i += d += 2) {
    System.out.println(array[i]);
}
```

Comment: просто интересно. Почему while? Почему не for?

Comment: @pavel можно сделать и `for`, как удобно :)

Comment: При запуске программы на консоле : 000 (нули).

Comment: @ИванИванов, а вы в массив-то что-нибудь записали?

Answer (score 0):

На псевдоязыке будет так

```
var index = 0;

while (index * index < array.length)
{
    print(array[index*index]);

    index ++;
}
```

Полный квадрат - натуральное число, корень из которого также является натуральным числом.

Это значит что квадрат любого натурального числа является полным квадратом. На этом и основан приведенный код - коротко, дешево и сердито :)

Приведенный выше код как раз является наименьшим исходником для твоей задачи (как мне кажется). Ну разве что 0 не является полным квадратом и индексом, но тут просто присвой индексу в начале 1.

Comment: ну кстати 0 -полный квадрат... Чисто формально.